# How effective is disabling Firefox's geo.enabled setting for increasing anonymity?

Tags: anonymity, firefox, geolocation

When viewing the bottom of a Google Search page, you can see that Google shows more or less your precise location, determined by your IP. This is useful for Google Maps.

In `about:config` is a switch `geo.enabled` which should disable this feature.

Of course using a VPN, Tor, etc. is considered for anonymity, but might the switch be also good?

Does disabling this only affect Google Search pages, or also other websites?

Comment: the switch means you won't even be asked to share location, but if you always click NO anyways, the effect on privacy would be the same.

Comment: Yes it is so, however it seems it's still using the ip but not to search the precise location. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[`geo.enabled`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config_entries#Geo.) is a Firefox configuration setting that controls [location-aware browsing](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/geolocation/).  From that page:

> When you visit a location-aware website, Firefox will ask you if you want to share your location.
>
> If you consent, Firefox gathers information about nearby wireless access points and your computer’s IP address. Then Firefox sends this information to the default geolocation service provider, Google Location Services, to get an estimate of your location. That location estimate is then shared with the requesting website.

If you are concerned about anonymity, I highly recommend using [the Tor Browser Bundle](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en) for your browsing.

Comment: Yes I know Tor or also some vpn-services. It means it works just with Firefox and within Google-search. Thank you.